# KeyError in ORM code when annotating using a Case and aggregating the annotation in a group by

Tags: django

We encountered this issue in a pretty complex project, but I've managed to reproduce it in a dummy project:

This is django 1.11.7 on python3.6 and postgres10:

#### models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Thing(models.Model):

    multiplierA = models.IntegerField()
    multiplierB = models.IntegerField()


class Data(models.Model):

    thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing')
    multiplier_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', 'use multiplier A'), ('B', 'use multiplier B')))
    option = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 'option 1'), (2, 'option 2')))
    percentage = models.FloatField()
```

#### tests.py:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, FloatField, IntegerField, Sum, When
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Data, Thing


class AnnotateTests(TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):

        thing = Thing.objects.create(multiplierA=2, multiplierB=3)

        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='A', option=1, percentage=0.2)
        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='A', option=2, percentage=0.3)
        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='A', option=3, percentage=0.1)

        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='B', option=1, percentage=0.1)
        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='B', option=2, percentage=0.4)
        Data.objects.create(thing=thing, multiplier_choice='B', option=3, percentage=0.5)


        whens = [
            When(multiplier_choice='A', then=F('thing__multiplierA')),
            When(multiplier_choice='B', then=F('thing__multiplierB'))
        ]

        multiplier_case = Case(*whens, output_field=IntegerField(), default=0)


        qs = (Data.objects
              # select only certain options to sum up for each thing:
              .filter(thing=thing, option__in=[1, 2])
              # select the correct multiplier
              .annotate(multiplier=multiplier_case)
              # group by thing => sum of percentage * multiplier
              .values('thing')
              .annotate(amount_sum=Sum(F('percentage') * F('multiplier')))
              .values('amount_sum'))

        print(qs.values('thing__id', 'amount_sum'))
```

Running this test will result in the following traceback:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_simple (annotate.tests.AnnotateTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robin/src/ormweirdness/annotate/tests.py", line 34, in test_simple
    .annotate(amount_sum=Sum(F('percentage') * F('multiplier')))
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 945, in annotate
    clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 973, in add_annotation
    summarize=is_summary)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 19, in resolve_expression
    c = super(Aggregate, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 548, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 412, in resolve_expression
    c.rhs = c.rhs.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 471, in resolve_expression
    return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/Users/robin/.virtualenvs/ormweirdness/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1472, in resolve_ref
    return self.annotation_select[name]
KeyError: 'multiplier'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've found person that also seemed to have this problem on the [django-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/SYAGaVuEjHY). Unfortunately, no replies.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still think the above approach should work (bug in the ORM?), I've found that moving the multiplication to the `Case` statement and using the `Case` statement directly in the `Sum` stops this problem because now the `Sum` doesn't have to do an annotation lookup:

```
whens = [
    When(multiplier_choice='A', then=F('thing__multiplierA') * F('percentage')),
    When(multiplier_choice='B', then=F('thing__multiplierB') * F('percentage'))
]

multiplier_case = Case(*whens, output_field=FloatField(), default=0)


data_qs = (Data.objects
           # select only certain options to sum up for each thing:
           .filter(thing=thing, option__in=[1, 2])
           .values('thing')
           # group by thing => sum of percentage * multiplier
           .annotate(amount_sum=Sum(multiplier_case))
           .values('amount_sum')
           .order_by('thing'))
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
               WHEN "annotate_data"."multiplier_choice" = A THEN ("annotate_thing"."multiplierA" * "annotate_data"."percentage")
               WHEN "annotate_data"."multiplier_choice" = B THEN ("annotate_thing"."multiplierB" * "annotate_data"."percentage")
               ELSE 0
           END) AS "amount_sum"
FROM "annotate_data"
INNER JOIN "annotate_thing" ON ("annotate_data"."thing_id" = "annotate_thing"."id")
WHERE ("annotate_data"."thing_id" = 1
       AND "annotate_data"."option" IN (1,
                                        2))
GROUP BY "annotate_data"."thing_id"
ORDER BY "annotate_data"."thing_id" ASC
```

If anyone finds a solution that does not imply repeating the whole calculation (which might be far more complex than the one we're doing) inside of each `When`, I'll accept your answer as the solution :)